# SoapClient call works on PHP 5.6 but not on PHP 7

Tags: php, soap-client, php-7

I have a soapClient call that works fine with PHP 5.6 (RH6). We are upgrading the system to PHP 7 (RH7 with the same configuration as the previous one) but the same call does not work.

This is my code

```
$wsdlUrl = "https://THE_URL_I_AM_CALLING/repository/soap/2.1?wsdl";
$sslClientCert =  "../../app/config/ssl/ssl_cert.crt";
$sslClientKey =  "../../app/config/ssl/ssl_cert.key";

$proxy = 'proxy_http';
$port = 8080;

$contextOptions = [
    'ssl' => [
        'local_cert' => $sslClientCert,
        'local_pk' =>  $sslClientKey,
        'SNI_enabled' => true,
        'SNI_server_name' => 'THE_URL_I_AM_CALLING'
    ]
];

$options= [
    "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,
    "features" => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
    "stream_context" => stream_context_create($contextOptions),
    'proxy_host'     => $proxy,
    'proxy_port'     => $port
];

$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $options);

try {
        // execute the search
        $searchResults = $client->searchDocuments([
            "text" => "myText",
            "hint" => "document"
        ]);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

the error I get under PHP 7 is

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host

if I make the call using CURL it works.

I would rather use clientSoap to make my life easier.

Comment: check you have enable `soap` in `php7`

Comment: I checked. it is enabled

Comment: You say that you're upgrading, have you compared the enabled extensions and settings between 5.6 and 7? Since you're unable to connect to the host, it sounds like an SSL related issue. Verify the `openssl` extension is enabled. I would also try changing the relative URI's to the cert files, in favor of using `dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/app/config/ssl/...'` Otherwise try adding `"ssl" => array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false)` to your `contextOptions`, to validate its not a cert issue. You may need to define `curl.cainfo` and `openssl.cafile` in your php.ini

Comment: I am unable to connect with soapClient. But I can connect with CURL (using the certificate and key). openssl is enabled on the new server and all other settings are the same. When I update the `contextOptions` array I get `Bad Request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Posting it here so no other soul on earth needs to go through this ordeal.

According to the documentation 
http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#context.ssl.sni-server-name

> **SNI_server_name** (*string*): 
>   If set, then this value will be used as server name for server name indication. If this value is not set, then the server name is guessed based on the hostname used when opening the stream.
>
> Note:  This option is deprecated, in favour of peer_name, as of PHP
>   5.6.0.

After changing:

```
'SNI_server_name' => 'THE_URL_I_AM_CALLING'
```

with

```
'peer_name' => 'THE_URL_I_AM_CALLING'
```

It works.